# Full Outer Join - Save Output in new table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables that I'm trying to join into one.

I ran the following code successfully.

```
SELECT * FROM combined
LEFT OUTER JOIN isbn_price
ON combined.isbn13 = isbn_price.isbn;
```

My question is how do I save this output into a new table? Or even append the joined columns from isbn_price onto the combined table?

Thanks!

Comment: I want to create a new table from the output of this join.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create the table on the fly:

```
SELECT * 
INTO NewTable
FROM combined
LEFT OUTER JOIN isbn_price
ON combined.isbn13 = isbn_price.isbn;
```

Comment: Does this create a new table in the database or just a temp table?

Comment: This creates a new permanent table. To create a temp table, use the hash in front of the table name, that makes it temporary - #NewTable