# error1064 using phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, mariadb

I can't understand why sql gave me an error #1064. I just followed the instruction at this
[Full Outer Join - Save Output in new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842337/full-outer-join-save-output-in-new-table)

I tried putting "INSERT" syntax before the "INTO" but the error is the same

```
SELECT *  
INTO newtable
FROM buyers FULL JOIN product 
ON product.product_id = buyers.product_id
```

I expect it to run ok, but mysql gave me this error:

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INTO newtable FROM buyers FULL JOIN product ON
>   product.product_id = buyers.pr' at line 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for mysql (phpmyadmin)   you need  create select   (and not select INTO as use in Sqlite)

```
 create table newtable
 SELECT *  
 FROM buyers FULL JOIN product 
    ON product.product_id = buyers.product_id
```

but looking to your ON clause  instead of a FULL JOIN seems you need  INNER or LEFT  JOIN

```
 create table newtable
 SELECT *  
 FROM buyers INNER JOIN product 
    ON product.product_id = buyers.product_id
```

or 
     create table newtable
     SELECT *
     FROM buyers LEFT JOIN product 
        ON product.product_id = buyers.product_id

depending of exact match or not

or for a cartesain product you should use FULL JOIN this way

```
 create table newtable
 SELECT *  
 FROM buyers FULL JOIN product
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try This One

```
SELECT *  
FROM newtable
WHERE buyers INNER JOIN product 
ON product.product_id = buyers.product_id
```

IS THIS DO YOU WANT?